# References in names and descriptions of embedded files with navigator

Tags: hyperref, cross-referencing, bookmarks, navigation, embedding

I want to attach several files to a document and name them according to the Figure, Table etc. they belong to. I use the `navigator` package to do this, but I am unable to get it to work properly.

What I want:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{navigator}

\begin{filecontents*}[overwrite]{attachment.txt}
This is an attachment
\end{filecontents*}

\begin{document}
\section{Section 1}
\label{section1}
\embeddedfile[Attachment for Section \ref{section1}]{attachment}[Section\ref{section1}.txt]{./attachment.txt}
\end{document}
```

If I run this without including the package `hyperref`, it works on the second run, presumably because the references need to be created first. However, the references in the file name and description are rendered as “Section 1hbox{}”.
If I include the `hyperref` package, nothing works anymore and I get the follwing errors for the line with `\embeddedfile`:

```
! Argument of \@sect has an extra }.
! Paragraph ended before \@sect was complete.
```

Answer (score 1):

I wouldn't use `navigator` together with `hyperref`.  Both packages try to handle a quite similar set of PDF features, and in a number of places they clash, for example as both write to the catalog and the info dictionary.

If you want to use navigator use it for everything, but be aware that it is missing one important feature of `hyperref`: It doesn't have an equivalent to `\pdfstringdef` which converts TeX input to something safe in a PDF string.

This leads to your error: \ref is a rather complex command, but `navigator` expects that the description and alternate file name is something simple, that can be handled by `\pdfescapestring`. Using `\pdfstringdef` doesn't work, as then the description is escaped twice.

With embedfile instead of navigator your example could be done like this (here too one need to avoid \ref in the filespec).

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{zref-user}
\usepackage{embedfile}

\begin{filecontents*}{attachment.txt}
This is an attachment
\end{filecontents*}
\makeatletter
\newcommand\expref[1]{\zref@extract{#1}{default}}
\makeatother
\begin{document}
\section{Section 1}
\label{section1}\zlabel{section1}

\embedfile [filespec=Section\expref{section1}.txt,
desc=Attachment for Section \expref{section1}]{attachment.txt}

\end{document}
```